# a task is not mentioned as skipped if it is skipped

Tags: ansible

In a folder I have a playbook:

```
---
- hosts: cent8
  gather_facts: true
  become: yes

  roles:
    - Ansible-RHEL8-CIS-Benchmarks
```

The tasks are in "*tasks*" folder in the "*Ansible-RHEL8-CIS-Benchmarks*" roles folder (current folder, where above playbook resides in). The roles path is being configued in ansible.cfg file:

```
[defaults]
roles_path = ../
```

I execute tasks from "*tasks/level-1/1.1.18.yml*" (tasks tagged with "1.1.18" in this file)

```
---
- name: 1.1.18 - Ensure sticky bit is set on all world-writable directories - changed_when false
  shell: df --local -P|awk 'NR>1{print $6}'|xargs -I {} find {} -xdev -type d \( -perm -0002 -a ! -perm -1000 \)
  register: shell_output
  changed_when: shell_output.stdout_lines | length > 0
  tags:
    - "1.1.18"

- name: 1.1.18 - Checking or Setting permissions on the world-writable directories
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    mode: a+t
  with_items:
    - "{{ shell_output.stdout_lines }}"
  changed_when: shell_output.stdout_lines | length > 0
  tags:
    - "1.1.18"
```

Everything works fine but I don't understand why there is no note: "skipping: [192.168.170.222]
" beneath the last task `"1.1.18 - Checking or Setting permissions on the world-writable directories]`", which is being skipped (it is only mentioned in summary as skipped=1):

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -t 1.1.18

PLAY [cent8] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.170.222]

TASK [Ansible-RHEL8-CIS-Benchmarks : Preflight - Fail if host is not suitable for this benchmark] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.170.222]

TASK [Ansible-RHEL8-CIS-Benchmarks : 1.1.18 - Ensure sticky bit is set on all world-writable directories - changed_when false] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.170.222]

TASK [Ansible-RHEL8-CIS-Benchmarks : 1.1.18 - Checking or Setting permissions on the world-writable directories] ****************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.170.222            : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The source of the tasks can be found on https://github.com/HarryHarcourt/Ansible-RHEL8-CIS-Benchmarks

I use the latest Ansible version `ansible [core 2.11.3]` installed with command:

```
python3.8 -m pip install --user ansible
```

Comment: From the same dir you launched your playbook, issue `ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK`. I very strongly suspect it returns something else than `default`. In that case, check in the configured `stdout_callback` documentation that it does not remove skipped hosts from the output (like e.g. `skippy`). You can also go back to default in that case (check the file reported in the above output and remove the corresponding `stdout_callback=XXXXX` line) and the skipped host will be displayed again.

Comment: @Zeitounator - the "dump" command returns "default": `$ ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK
DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK(default) = default`. In the ansible.cfg I have: `callback_enabled = profile_tasks`

Comment: Which version of Ansible are you running?

Comment: @Zeitounator - I believe this is latest version of ansible, I installed it as an regular user with command `python3.8 -m pip install --user ansible` (there is no ansible installed by admin on this system, no ansible on rpm -qa output)

Comment: `ansible [core 2.11.3]
  config file = /home/user/Ansible-RHEL8-CIS-Benchmarks/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/user/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.3 (default, Aug  2 2021, 06:46:27) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
  jinja version = 3.0.1
  libyaml = True`

Comment: This would be better as an edit to your question. Comments are volatile and not meant for large portions of code/output.

Answer (score 1):

## Empiric testing

I'll let you dig in the source code if you want to understand why (I did not). As far as I am concerned the final result is strictly the same: the task isn't played.

From what I could test, when the argument to `loop`/`with_items`/`with_list` is a jinja2 templated empty list, ansible does not even bother to enter the loop and simply displays the task title.

If you pass a static empty list then the `skipped` info you are looking for is displayed. Note that passing a list of lists to `with_items` automatically flattens the first level and you then drop in the first scenario again, even with static arguments. See the [`item` lookup documentation page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/items_lookup.html#synopsis) for more info

IMO, the first behavior is the closest to what is really happening: I have no elements in my loop so I'm not even skipping any iteration since there are none.

Here is my ansible version:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.11.3] 
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) [GCC 9.4.0]
  jinja version = 2.11.3
  libyaml = True
```

This is the demo playbook I tested with:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Loop on a templated empty list
      debug:
        msg: "I'm doing nothing and I won't be called"
      with_items: "{{ [] }}"
      # You get the same behavior with
      # loop: "{{ [] }}"
      # with_list: "{{ [] }}"

    - name: Loop on a statically passed empty list
      debug:
        msg: "I'm lazy as well so no one calls me either"
      with_items: []
      # You get the same behavior with
      # loop: []
      # with_list: []

    - name: Demonstrating automagic flatenning on item lookup with list of lists
            (same behavior as templated empty list)
      debug:
        msg: "Please leave me alone, don't call me!"
      with_items:
        - []
        - []
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Loop on a templated empty list] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Loop on a statically passed empty list] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Demonstrating automagic flatenning on item lookup with list of lists (same behavior as templated empty list)] *******************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```